# How to create Visual Studio 2008 .vcproj file from Qt's project file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt

I am using Qt4.8.0 for creating an application. I wanted to create a MSVC 2008 project file from Qt's .pro project file for "Win32 Release" configuration.
I used the following to create the project file. However the generated .vcproj file only has "x64" configuration.

```
qmake -tp vc -r -spec win32-msvc2008 "CONFIG += Release"
```

I used the same command with Qt4.7.4 and it did created .vcproj file with "Release|Win32" configuration. But with Qt4.8.0 it only created .vcproj file with "x64" configuration.

I have mentioned following in the common.pri file:

```
CONFIG += x86
CONFIG -= x86_64
QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE += /MACHINE:X86 /LTCG
```

Can someone please help me to generate .vcproj file for "Release|Win32" configuration please.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You are running it from the x64 cross compile tools shell - use theregular vcvars32.bat one

Comment: Yes, I am using regular vcvars32.bat. It still is not generating .vcproj file with x86 configuration.